# Como incluir uma linha no início de um arquivo de texto?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Meu sistema gera um arquivo de texto, e com base na soma de uma informação que consta em cada linha, ele faz o cálculo de um dígito verificador.

Porém, esse resultado deve estar na primeira linha do arquivo, como posso fazer para incluir essa linha no início?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simples. Você só precisa

1. Ler todo o arquivo e salvar numa lista de `string`, onde cada linha represente uma string na lista
2. Inserir a nova linha na posição 0 da lista
3. Escrever todas as `strings` da lista no arquivo

```
const string nomeArquivo = "arquivo.txt";

List<string> linhas = File.ReadAllLines(nomeArquivo).ToList(); // Passo 1
linhas.Insert(0, "Primeira linha"); // Passo 2
File.WriteAllLines(nomeArquivo, linhas); // Passo 3
```